# MongoDB: aggregate 3 collections from different DBs

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have three collections in three different MongoDB: db books( book collection), db autor (autor collection) and db rating (rating collection). I want to aggregate this collections....

```
autor {"autorId" : "1", "autorname" : "Andre"}
rating {"autorId": "1", "bookId": "23", "rating": "3"}
book {"bookId": "23", "bookname": "Sommer"}
```

and to have a csv. file with fields: bookname, autorname, rating. Can I do this with MongoDB. I have tried to aggregate two collections with $lookup...

```
var bookrating = db.autor.aggregate([{ 
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "rating",                                        
            localField: "autorId",
            foreignField: "autorId",                                    
            as: "ratingdata"
        }
    }
])

db.bookrating.insert(bookrating);
```

How can I do this with three collections? Is it possible to do with MongoDB??? Could you help me, please?

Comment: You said your collections are in different DBs, so I am wonder if you got any results when use `$lookup` on two collections?

Comment: Yes, You are right, I checkt it, the array is empty :(

Comment: Why do you need to use different DBs?